# Set session cookies for specific subdomains

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain

I have a website with multiple subdomains, which share a unique PHP session cookie to identify each user. I did this by simply adding `session.cookie_domain = '.mydomain.com'`, however I'm wondering if it's possible to specify more than one subdomain, so that cookies will only get sent to, for example, `www.mydomain.com` and `user.mydomain.com` but won't in `images.mydomain.com`.
Would this be possible?

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->setDomain($domain)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L117) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie). This lets you share the cookie with all subdomains or not at all. All other scenarios are not possible as per the HTTP specification.

Answer (score 2):

No, those would have to be 2 separate cookies.

You would have to create a sub-domain like `sub.mydomain.com`, have hosts like `www.sub.mydomain.com` etc., and set cookies for `.sub.mydomain.com` if you wanted to isolate cookies in that way...

Answer (score -1):

for future users, actually you can just rename the cookie id and you can have specific cookie for that subdomain

Comment: Read question again, question is about one cookie shared by two subdomains, but not by third.

Comment: but may do i ask this cookie is for authentication ? something like user login  ?