# How to set session for specific subdomain in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, session, cookies

I have a login page which exist in my main domain. I want to set session some specific subdomain.

Suppose My login page is `example.com` After successfully login my page will go to `cms.example.com` or `admin.example.com`. Session should store this three `example.com`, `cms.example.com` and `admin.example.com` not other subdomain.

Currently I got session only my `example.com` but I am unable to get any session  in above 2 subdomain.

I found some related question and answer here [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains) | [Set session cookies for specific subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027685/set-session-cookies-for-specific-subdomains) but this is set for all domains. Here is problem because I have some other subdomains like `user.example.com`, `studio.example.com`, `demo.example.com` etc.

How to set session for specific domain and subdomain?

Comment: Separate servers? Are you storing session data in a shared database?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No, I store in same server

Answer (score 0):

Sessions can't travel to sub domains. If you want to send a session to 2 different sub domains and not to the rest I'd recommend using cookies and set them to a specific folder containing the subdomain. If that is not what you are looking for you can set it for all sub domains:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."), 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you've already included a file that [takes the domain and lops off the sub domain.](http://www.epigroove.com/blog/using-php-sessions-across-subdomains)

I had the similar issue. I solved it by this trick.

### Method 1:

Add a prefix before your sessions distinguishing session for your sub domains.
For Example: `$_Session["cms.id"], $_Session["admin.id"]`

### Method 2:

Create a class for sessions with attributes **domain** and rest of the information you want to store.

```
class CustomSessions{
private $domain;
private $userId;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDomain()
{
    return $this->domain;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $domain
 */
public function setDomain($domain)
{
    $this->domain = $domain;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getUserId()
{
    return $this->userId;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $userId
 */
public function setUserId($userId)
{
    $this->userId = $userId;
}

}
```

Now you can create CustomSession object and set **$domain** with the domain you want that session to be used in.

```
$obj = new CustomSession();
$obj->setDomain("cms.example.com");
```

You can then check in your sub-domains the value of $domain and carry your logic accordingly.

```
if($obj->getDomain()=='cms.example.com'){
// your code goes here
}
```

Comment: I am not asking about Distributing session `$_Session["id"]` should work in `example.com`, `cms.example.com` and `admin.example.com` because my all three file code is one. pointed also one directory.